# Angular 5 Animations are not working on iOS 10.3 Safari

Tags: angular, mobile-safari, angular5, angular-animations, web-animations

I'm using **@angular/animations** on my page. It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari(Desktop) but the divs that has animation are not visible in Safari (iOS).

I imported **web-animations-js** in my **polyfills.ts** file.

```
**versions**
npm 5.5.1 
@angular/animations: "5.1.1" 
@angular/cli: "1.6.1"
@angular/compiler-cli: "5.1.0" 
web-animations-js: "^2.3.1"
```

Comment: How do you import web-animations-js in polyfills.ts ?

Comment: @br.julien import 'web-animations-js';

Comment: Try also with *import 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min';* or *require('web-animations-js/web-animations.min');*

Comment: @br.julien I tried both. Didn't work.

Comment: Another idea would be to put it first in the list of the imports, if it's not already done

Comment: @br.julien Putting the line on top of the page didn't work either..

Comment: Did u find any solution to this issue? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  polyfill
in polyfills.ts

remove comments from

`import web-animations-js;`

then run

`npm install --save web-animations-js`